# Why Wireless NIC Loses Its Lease To Router?

Tags: wireless-networking, nat, connection, hotspot, event-viewer

This constantly started to happen some time ago. I connect to my router andand lose every few seconds connection to router and it reconnects again. I have screenshooted most errors that **Event Viewer** reported. First comes overview:

[image]

And now 3 events that happened at the same time:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you noticed, all 3 came at same time, when first was warning saying something about **semaphore timeout**, second was about **losing lease** and last was about **NAT**.

After several minutes of this happening, i could not connect to router as NIC showed that it was aquiring address and just repeated connection attempts until i just had to cancel connection. You can see this in Event Viewer:

[image]

This problem happens with other hotspots as well.

Answer (score 2):

This could be caused by a few things, but looks to be specific to your NIC.

Try these steps:

- Upgrade the NIC drivers
- Try and get alternate drivers working (uninstall custom drivers and see what windows comes up with via windows update, or install vendor specific drivers)
- Boot to **Ubuntu** via a live CD, and see if you experience the issues under a different OS.
- See if any high network traffic applications are consistently running when this happens.
- [Wireless Zero Configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Zero_Configuration) might be interfering, disable the service.
- Disable any 3rd party firewall software you may have running (or other related security software) to see if the issue solves itself.
- Try clearing the ARP cache when renewal fails (See [Method 4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314067))

  - `netsh interface ip delete arpcache`

As an additional debugging step to ensure it was NIC related would be to use another external wireless adapter (like a USB based NIC) to see if it would also experience the same problems under your OS.

Comment: That's pretty logical solution you advice here Sara. Do you know if it is possible to boot to Ubuntu directly from CD or other external media? Thanks.

Comment: Yes booting can be achieved easily via CD/DVD, or if your motherboard supports it you can do it via a correctly configured USB.

Comment: Should i burn it on CD-R or CD-RW media? I know it gets updated often and hence this question.

Comment: CD-R is fine, they're very cheap, and the time that'll pass between needing to burn the next version will be a while.